# ErrorBar Plot Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am ploting in Matlab using errorbar() function. I have a set of data with mean, max and min values but some points the max and min match the mean value. Therefore when I plkot errorbar I get something like:
[image]

The thing is that I would not like to have these horizontal lines. The vertical ones are those in which the mean differs from max an min which I still want to keep.  Any help?

```
pd: h1= errorbar(x,y,min,max)
```

Comment: Have you read through this doc yet? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbarseriesproperties.html

Comment: Yes! But does not says anything about this singular case. You can change line Styles but the only thing I want is to get  a point in those that mean max and min are equal

Answer (score 1):

You could plot two series:

```
h1 = plot(x,y); % for the central points
idx = min ~= max;
h2 = errorbar(x(idx),y(idx),min(idx), max(idx));
```